# MutableSharedFlow not trigger same event twice in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am using `MutableSharedFlow` in project. My main project concept is very big, so I cannot add in here, instead I made a very small sample to reproduce my problem. I know this example is very wrong, but I have same scenario in my main project. I am using `MutableSharedFlow` as a `Queue` implementation with single Thread execution with the help of `Mutex`.

**ExampleViewModel**

```
class ExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val serviceNumber = ServiceNumber()
    val serviceNumberEventFlow = serviceNumber.eventFlow
    val mutex = Mutex()
    var delayCounter = 0

    suspend fun addItem(itemOne: Int = 2, itemTwo: Int = 2): Add {
        return mutex.queueWithTimeout("add") {
            serviceNumberEventFlow.onSubscription {
                serviceNumber.add(itemOne, itemTwo)
                delayCounter++
                if (delayCounter == 1) {
                    delay(1000)
                    Log.w("Delay ", "Delay Started")
                    serviceNumber.add(8, 8)
                }
            }.firstOrNull {
                it is Add
            } as Add? ?: Add("No value")
        }
    }

    suspend fun subItem(itemOne: Int = 2, itemTwo: Int = 2): Sub {
            return mutex.queueWithTimeout("sub") {
            serviceNumberEventFlow.onSubscription {
                serviceNumber.sub(itemOne, itemTwo)
            }.firstOrNull {
                it is Sub
            } as Sub? ?: Sub("No value")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun <T> Mutex.queueWithTimeout(
        action: String, timeout: Long = 5000L, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
    ): T {
        return try {
            withLock {
                return@withLock withTimeout<T>(timeMillis = timeout, block = block)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Wrong", " $e Timeout on BLE call: $action")
            throw e
        }
    }
}

class ServiceNumber : Number {
    val eventFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Event>(extraBufferCapacity = 50)
    private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)

    override fun add(itemOne: Int, itemTwo: Int) {
        Log.i("ServiceNumber", " Add event trigger with $itemOne -- $itemTwo")
        eventFlow.emitEvent(Add("Item added ${itemOne + itemTwo}"))
    }

    override fun sub(itemOne: Int, itemTwo: Int) {
        eventFlow.emitEvent(Sub("Item subtract ${itemOne - itemTwo}"))
    }

    private fun <T> MutableSharedFlow<T>.emitEvent(event: T) {
        scope.launch { emit(event) }
    }
}

interface Number {
    fun add(itemOne: Int, itemTwo: Int)
    fun sub(itemOne: Int, itemTwo: Int)
}

sealed class Event
data class Add(val item: String) : Event()
data class Sub(val item: String) : Event()
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: ExampleViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Theme {
                Column {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                val result = viewModel.addItem()
                                Log.e("Result", "$result")
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Add")
                    }
                    Button(onClick = {
                        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
                            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                val result = viewModel.subItem()
                                Log.e("Result", "$result")
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Sub")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Theme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    MaterialTheme(content = content)
}
```

**Problem**

This example is simple **Add** and **subtract** of two number. When I am click on **Add** Button first time, `viewmodel.addItem(...)` -> `...` ->`ServiceNumber.add()` will trigger and `emit` the value and we can see log in console. Inside the **Add** Button function, I was also added a `delay` to trigger `ServiceNumber.add()` again to see that `onSubscription` will be also retrigger or not. `MutableSharedFlow` emit the value as I can see in log but `onSubscription` method not called. I don't understand what is the problem in here.

[image]

Comment: I don’t see where you’re calling addItem() again after a delay in the code above. Note that `onSubscription` is an operator, not a mutator, so it returns a new copy of the SharedFlow that you’re releasing to GC by the end of `addItem()` since you don’t store it and merely call `firstOrNull()` on before dropping the reference.

Comment: Instead of `serviceNumber.add(8, 8)` this, I have to call `addItem(8,8)`again ?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sorry I didn't see you have updated your first comment. My question is when I added delay in my code and used `serviceNumber.add(8, 8)`  why `onSubscription` is not trigger again? If I want to trigger `onSubscription` again I want to call my `addItem` function again?

Answer (score 0):

`onSubscription` is an *operator* so it creates a *new copy* of your shared flow. The lambda code will only be run when there are new collectors on this new flow. The only time you collect this new flow is when you call `firstOrNull()` on it, a terminal operator that collects a single value.

Comment: Can you please provide the example, How can I recieved the new value which is emitted by flow? I am confused where should I use `firstOnNull`..

Comment: Maybe later. I still haven’t had time to analyze that GitHub project to understand what this is even supposed to do. At first glance it looked very complicated.